# A monospace font with distinct symbols

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a monospace font to display passwords to the user. A common problem with many fonts is that certain symbols look too similar. For example, `l` and `1` may be confused and the user may read off a wrong password. What are good monospace fonts with distinct symbols?

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few unique monospace fonts to choose from that fit these requirements. Personally, I'd go with the classic [OCR-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR-A#Space.2C_digits.2C_and_unaccented_letters) or OCR-B, as these typefaces are designed for each individual character to be optically recognizable by both computers and people:

[image]

*Note:* OCR stands for "Optical Character Recognition", a good choice to use a font that is built for this type of application.

Here's another resource if this typeface doesn't work for you:
[Samples of monospaced typefaces (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces)

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. Ended up with Consolas, for now at least.